# Is property losing metadata in the expression x => x.AccountNumber.ToString() using FlientValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, fluentvalidation

I'm building an web app for a personal project and came accross an unusual behaviour using FlientValidation in a RESTful API with .NET 5.0, following the [current trend](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36655.onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc.aspx). Anyway, cutting to the chase:

This is my DTO:

```
public class ClientDto
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public int? AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public int InitialFunds { get; set; }
}
```

A have a validator for it, no more than 5 digits for `AccountNumber`

```
public class ClientDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<ClientDto>
{
    public ClientDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ClientName).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber.ToString()).MaximumLength(5).When(x => x.AccountNumber != null);
    }
}
```

If I try to insert invalid data for `AccountNumber` (say, 6 digits), this is the server response:

```
{ 
    {
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "The length of '' must be 5 characters or fewer. You entered 6 characters."
        ]
    }
}
```

Where is the property name? This is the JSON request I just tried to send:

```
{
  "ClientName" : "Mike",
  "AccountNumber" : 123456 
}
```

Should try an `AccountNumber`, say, 12345, the server returns 200. ClientName also validates correctly:

```
{
  "ClientName" : "",
  "AccountNumber" : 12345
}
```

response:

```
{
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
     "errors": {
        "ClientName": [
            "'Client Name' must not be empty."
        ]
    }
}
```

Back to the Validator, if I swap the rule to something simple

```
//RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber.ToString()).MaximumLength(5).When(x => x.AccountNumber != null);
RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber).NotNull().NotEmpty();
```

A request like this

```
{
  "ClientName" : null,
  "AccountNumber" : null
}
```

will show both that fields' names are coming from somewhere down the .NET pipeline:

```
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"errors": {
    "ClientName": [
        "'Client Name' must not be empty."
    ],
    "AccountNumber": [
        "'Account Number' must not be empty."
    ]
}
```

My bets are on calling `.ToString()` in `RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber.ToString())` but I'm no CLR expert. Nor a "FluentValidator expert" for that matter. Thoughts?

Comment: It's using expressions which it decompiles. It's looking for a member expression to take the name of (property or field) but it's doesn't get that, it gets a method call expression. So it's defaulting to blank. Makes sense to me. Is your account number really numeric, or does it just so happen to be a (possibly 0-padded) string of all numbers? If the latter change the data type to a string and validate its all numbers (and perform the conversion/mapping when storing it, if you insist on using an integral type in your DB). Otherwise test if the value is less than 100,000

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about something along those lines as well. Unfortunatelly account number is an `Integer32` all the way down to the database. I don't think there's another way to do it with FluentValidator unless going the custom validators route, is there?

Comment: And note, your title refers to credit card number. Despite being all numbers and the fact it has "number" in its name, its not automatically an actual *number*. Just like a telephone number shouldn't be stored as an integer, nor should an account number or credit card number. You're not going to add two phone numbers or account numbers together. If you wanna validate a CC is valid (checksums and whatnot) you'd process the digits individually anyways. . The number that you *would* store would typically be an internal primary key (like an identity integer)

Comment: Store it as an integer in the database if you must... But use a string in your API models (you aren't exposing database types externally... Right?) and then use a tool like automapper--or manually--to convert before storing it into and after reading it from the database

Comment: This is actually a practice test I'm taking, but good call on the CC validation stuff, I started with the Credit Card example but switched to bank account as there were less digits to validate. I think I'll keep the account number as an integer as I seem to have figured out how to validate it, but I'll be sure to switch the credit card to a string. As I it turns out, these numbers were supposed to be PKs, but I soon switch to auto-incremental Ids and never gave it a second thought

Comment: I think the answer below should be able to help you with a custom validation message. I've never used fluent validator but it looks like with some tweaks it could get you what you want

Comment: I got it, thanks man ;)

Answer (score 2):

Usage of ToString() in `RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber.ToString())` is the problem, it's no longer a member expression/rule for a DTO property but rather a string expression.

You shouldn't need to write custom code to handle this.

`Transform(x => x.AccountNumber, x => x.ToString()).MaximumLength(5).When(x => x.AccountNumber != null);` would be one way of doing it (note: [transform usage changed in version 9.5](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/transform.html#transforming-values)).

Another way?

`RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber).InclusiveBetween(1, 99999).When(x => x.AccountNumber != null);`

Because you're using `When` it's always going to be evaluated server-side, `Must` is another option. Could be more options available, the main thing is avoiding custom code if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, custom validation couldn't be easier. For this particular case I turned this

```
RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber.ToString()).MaximumLength(5).When(x => x.AccountNumber != null);
```

into this

```
RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber).Custom((accountNumber, context) =>
{
    if (accountNumber.ToString().Length > 5)
        context.AddFailure(@$"The length of 'AccountNumber' must be 5 characters or fewer. 
        You entered {accountNumber.ToString().Length} characters.");
}).When(x => x.AccountNumber != null);
```

It bypasses the whole problem with the framework not finding the property name. Even the message is customizable, but I kept it the same as the default:

```
{
  "ClientName" : "Joe",
  "AccountNumber" : 123456
}
```

responds

```
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-276c77469c6acd4a9bf6f353a5606327-d956a33f62c9eb46-00",
"errors": {
    "AccountNumber": [
        "The length of 'AccountNumber' must be 5 characters or fewer. You entered 6 characters."
    ]
}
```

Great stuff.

**EDIT**

Making it generic (I used a static class because I didn't see a reason why not to):

```
public static class CustomValidationRules
{
    public static void CheckMaxLengthValidationFailure<T>(int length, int maxLength, 
        string propertyName, FluentValidation.ValidationContext<T> validationContext)
    {
        if (length > maxLength)
            validationContext.AddFailure(@$"The length of {propertyName} must be {maxLength} 
            characters or fewer. You entered {length} characters.");
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
public class ClientDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<ClientDto>
{
    public ClientDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ClientName).NotNull().NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(x => x.CreditCardNumber).Custom((creditCardNumber, context) =>
        {
            CustomValidationRules.CheckMaxLengthValidationFailure(creditCardNumber.ToString().Length, 16, "CreditCardNumber", context);
        }).When(x => x.CreditCardNumber != null);


        RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber).Custom((accountNumber, context) =>
        {
            CustomValidationRules.CheckMaxLengthValidationFailure(accountNumber.ToString().Length, 5, "AccountNumber", context);
        }).When(x => x.AccountNumber != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 RuleFor(x => x.AccountNumber)
                .When(x => x.AccountNumber.HasValue == false)
                .WithMessage("Account Number' must not be empty.");
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: Thanks man, but that's not quite it. Be cool, I already solved it.